# Upper bound for the error magnitude

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

> For the function $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^x$ on the interval $[0,1]$, by using polynomial interpolation with $x_0 = 0$, $x_1 = 1/2$, and $x_2 = 1$,
>   find the upper bound for the magnitude
>   $$
> \max_{0 \leq x \leq 1} |\mathrm{e}^x - p_2(x)|
> $$

I'm confused on how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the expression of $p_2(x)$, then finding the maximum of $|e^x-p_2(x)|$ for $x\in[0,1]$ can be converted to the following question:$$\max_{x\in[0,1]} (e^x-p_2(x))$$ or $$\min_{x\in[0,1]} (e^x-p_2(x))$$
Then just let $g(x)=e^x-p_2(x)$ and find the critical points in $[0,1]$.

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

By https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange_Polynomial_Approximation or other usual sources,
$$
R(x)=f(x)-p(x)=\frac{x(x-\frac12)(x-1)}{3!}f^{(3)}(\xi)
$$
so that 
$$
\left|R\left(\tfrac12(1+s)\right)\right|\le \frac{e}{48}|s-s^3|,~~~s\in[-1,1]
$$
with extrema of the bounding function at $s=\pm\frac1{\sqrt3}$.